# What does DTS:ThreadHint do / means?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I was migrating some SSIS packages, updating variable values.
when I check the changes, somehow many DTS:ThreadHint changed from 1 to 0
[image]

What is this? I looked for that phrase but there's no clear answer to it.
Anyone knows?
Thank you.

Comment: Given that this attribute is only visible in the underlying xml/dtsx and not editable via properties windows, I'd chalk it up to "internals to SSIS and nothing to concern ourselves with" It _is_ curious what the default values appear to be. A Data Flow Task appears to not have the entry, SQL Server Agent Job Task has a value of 2, Execute SQL Task 0, File System Task 1. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  For VS 2017, targeting the same

Comment: Also just came accross this on an SSIS package diff - would be interested to know what it does - strange there's no MS explanation for it..?